# Can I eat shrimp veins in sushi?

Tags: sushi, safety, shrimp

I bought a sushi roll with shrimp, avacado, and cucumber and ate three-fourths of it before realizing that the shrimps hadn't been deveined. I could see quite a bit of the brown paste and I must have eaten some in the other pieces.

If the restaurant cooked the shrimp properly before making the roll, am I safe? It looks so disgusting with the vein left in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shrimp "veins" are actually the shrimp intestines.  They are unattractive and sometimes taste bad, but they are [harmless to eat](https://www.washingtonpost.com/food/interactive/2022/how-to-peel-devein-shrimp/).

However, if I was eating in a sushi restaurant that failed to devein shrimp, I would worry about what *else* they may have missed in their seafood prep.  One usually relies on sushi chefs to spot signs of parasite contamination, for example.

Comment: Needless to say but I won't be going back for exactly that reason... if they can miss something so obvious who knows what else is slipping through.